# Redis - How to expire key at the end of the month, with node js and moment

Tags: node.js, redis, momentjs

The problem: to expire a key of redis, at the end of the month, using a client of connection to redis from node js, and using moment to work with dates.

Answer (score 0):

The solution: use moment to obtain the remaining milliseconds until the last day of the month then, pass it to seconds (milliseconds / 1000) and with the redis client, assign the expiration time to the key.

```
...
let dateTo = moment().endOf('month').valueOf();
let expire = parseInt(dateTo/1000);
client.expireat('redisKeys', expire);
client.exec(function (_error, _result) {
   if (_error) {
      return cb(_error);
   }
   return cb(null, "done!");
});
...
```

then from the redis-cli you can consult with the **TTL** command:

```
redis_6379:0>TTL redisKey
21882
```

and you will obtain as a result a number, which represents the remaining life time of that key, in seconds.